# Cronjob for some specific time in each 5th minute

Tags: cron

I need to run a shell script in each 5 minutes and some seconds. As a example I need to run the job at 10.25.21 AM, 10.30.21 AM etc. I was able to run the file in each 5 minutes using below command. But I couldn't figure out how to set the seconds.Is it possible?

```
*/5 * * * *
```

Comment: maybe you could write a script that sleeps 21 seconds and then starts the original script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cron`  does not go down to sub-minute resolutions, you will need to find another way. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron